# It shows "You've entered too many arguments" for this formula

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I am using this current formula..

```
=IF((AND((IF(R2="Error",X2="Low")),AB2>=0,AB2<=5)),"Within","Exceed",IF(AND(IF(R2="Error",X2="Medium")),AB2>=0,AB2<=5),"Within","Exceed",IF(AND(IF(R2="Error",X2="High")),AB2>=0,AB2<=5),"Within","Exceed")))
```

and it displayed that I've entered too many arguments.

Since my data have many conditions...

```
Error & Low & Range = 0-5 days,
Error & Medium & Range = 0-3 days,
Error & High & Range = 0-3 days

Support & Low & Range = 0-7 days, 
Support & Medium & Range = 0-5 days,
Support & High & Range = 0-3 days
```

If it is within the range it will show "Within" if not, it will show "Exceed"

Is there any way to go around this?

Comment: Try to check if IFS function can help you: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/ifs-function-36329a26-37b2-467c-972b-4a39bd951d45

Answer (score 0):

*Your formula should be written like this:*

```
=IF(AND(R2="Error",X2="Low",AB2>=0,AB2<=5),"Within",IF(AND(R2="Error",X2="Medium",AB2>=0,AB2<=5),"Within",IF(AND(R2="Error",X2="High",AB2>=0,AB2<=5),"Within","Exceed")))
```

- You may adjust cell references in the Formula as needed.

For more on this issue [you may check this.](https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/2018/06/06/excel-nested-if-statement/)